# Update column based on another column in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this query:

```
SELECT ID, T2.code1, T2.code2, T2.mins
FROM Table AS T1, (
SELECT code1, code2, MIN(ID) AS mins
FROM Table GROUP BY code1, code2 HAVING count(*)>1
)  AS T2
WHERE T1.code1=T2.code1 And T1.code2=T2.code2;
```

Where Im getting all the rows having duplicates based on code1 and code2 and getting the minumum ID of the duplicate rows.

Now What I want to do is update the table to set the ID of the duplicate rows as the minimum one

I tried this but got an error in access: (operation must use an updateable query)

```
Update (
SELECT ID, T2.code1, T2.code2, T2.mins
FROM Table AS T1, (
SELECT code1, code2, MIN(ID) AS mins
FROM Table GROUP BY code1, code2 HAVING count(*)>1
)  AS T2
WHERE T1.code1=T2.code1 And T1.code2=T2.code2
) Set ID=T2.mins;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a temp table by use of Make-Table action query of aggregate piece then join in `UPDATE`. Access SQL requires update queries to retain [updateable (or non read-only)](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) condition which usually means direct tables and simple joined queries or any table/query that you can edit/add/delete in its datasheet view. Aggregate queries with `GROUP BY` are never updateable.

**Make-Table** Query

```
SELECT code1, code2, MIN(ID) AS mins 
INTO Temp
FROM Table 
GROUP BY code1, code2 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

**Update** Query

```
UPDATE Table t1 INNER JOIN Temp t2
ON t1.code1 = t2.code1 AND t1.code2 = t2.code2
SET t1.Col = t2.Mins;
```

Alternatively, try with domain aggregates like `DMax()`, `DMin()`, `DCount()`, etc. Below assumes *code* fields are number types:

```
UPDATE Table t1
SET t1.Col = DMin("ID", "Table", "code1=" & t1.code1 & " AND code2=" & t1.code2)
WHERE DCount("ID", "Table", "code1=" & t1.code1 & " AND code2=" & t1.code2) > 1
```